# Making a stopwatch ( user input change size style ) using assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16, stopwatch, emu8086

[error on word byte hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzAbA.png)  [org 0x0100]

I am working on a project in assembly.(stopwatch user input change style and size ) I am working in   (in 16 bit assembly in emu8086).
I have been working on this for a long time and could not find the problem in my code.
What I am doing is simply creating stopwatch which shows  time when user  enter input its  change  style and style  of  userInput

I have been trying for a long time to solve it but I can't find my mistake. If someone can find my mistake please let me know.
Thank you very much.

jmp start

h
;Orignal Time
hrs:    dw 0 ;WORD Byte
min:    dw 0
s:      dw 0
ms:     dw 0

;Lap Time
lhrs:   dw 0
lmin:   dw 0
ls:     dw 0
lms:    dw 0

oldkb:  dd 0 ; declare double word dd ;For the purpose of saving the old keyboard ISR

;Flags for Modes
sMode:  db 0
lMode:  db 0

;Flags for other functions
startTimer:  db 0
snapshot:    db 0
lapTime:     db 0

location:   db 6

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Clear Screen Sub Routine

clrscr:     pusha
push es

```
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax
        xor di, di
        mov ax, 0x720
        mov cx, 2000
        
        cld
        rep stosw
        
        pop es
        popa
        ret
```

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Print the Main Layout

printLayout:    pusha   ; push all 32 oprend size
push es

```
            mov ax, 0xB800
            mov es, ax
            
            mov di, 160
            
            mov byte[es:di+0], 'H'
            mov byte[es:di+2], 'R'
            mov byte[es:di+4], 'S'
            
            mov byte[es:di+8], ':'

            mov byte[es:di+12], 'M'
            mov byte[es:di+14], 'I'
            mov byte[es:di+16], 'N'

            mov byte[es:di+20], ':'
            
            mov byte[es:di+24], 'S'
            
            mov byte[es:di+28], ':'

            mov byte[es:di+34], 'M'
            mov byte[es:di+36], 'S'
            
            pop es
            popa
            ret
```

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Keyboard ISR

kbisr:          push ax

```
            in  al, 0x60
            
            ;Checking release code only

            cmp al, 147         ;checking for 'R'
            jz  reset
            jnz modChanger
```

reset:          ;Resetting the orginal time

```
            mov word [cs:hrs], 0
            mov word [cs:min], 0
            mov word [cs:s]   ,0
            mov word [cs:ms], 0

            ;Resetting the lap time
            
            mov word [cs:lhrs], 0
            mov word [cs:lmin], 0
            mov word [cs:ls], 0
            mov word [cs:lms], 0

            call clrscr

            mov byte [cs:location], 6

            jmp EOI1
```

modChanger:     cmp al, 170                     ;Release code of Shift Left
jnz checkLMode1

```
            mov byte [cs:lMode], 0          ;Disable the lap mode
            
            cmp byte [cs:sMode], 1          ;If sMode was already enabled then do nothing
            jz EOI1
            
            mov byte [cs:sMode], 1          ;Else enable the sMode
            jmp EOI1
```

checkLMode1:    cmp al, 182                     ;Release code of Shift Right
jnz startTime

```
            mov byte [cs:sMode], 0          ;Disable the split Mode
            
            cmp byte [cs:lMode], 1          ;If lMode was aleady enabled then do nothing
            jz  EOI1
            
            mov byte [cs:lMode], 1          ;Else enable the lMode
            jmp EOI1
```

;Scenarios when space key is released

startTime:      cmp al, 185
jnz oldKbHandler

```
            cmp byte [cs:startTimer], 1     ;If Timer is already started then do nothing
            jz  check0
            
            mov byte [cs:startTimer], 1     ;Else start the timer
```

check0:         cmp byte [cs:sMode], 1            ;If split mode is enabled
jnz  check1

```
            mov byte [cs:snapshot], 1
            jmp EOI1
```

check1:         cmp byte [cs:lMode], 1        ;Else if the lap mode is enabled
jnz EOI1

```
            mov byte [cs:lapTime], 1
            jmp EOI1
```

EOI1:           mov al,0x20                     ;End of Interrupt Signal
out 0x20,al

```
            pop ax
            iret
```

;Rest of the Keyboard keys are handled by the old keyboard ISR
oldKbHandler:   pop ax
jmp far [cs:oldkb]

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;To print the number on screen

printstr:   push bp
mov bp, sp
pusha

```
        push es
        
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax
        
        mov di, [bp+4]                  ;Location
        mov ax, [bp+6]                  ;Number
        
        mov bx, 10
        mov cx, 0
```

nextdigit:  mov dx, 0
div bx
add dl, 0x30
push dx
inc cx
cmp ax, 0
jnz nextdigit

```
        cmp cx, 1
        jnz nextpos
        mov byte [es:di], '0'
        add di, 2
```

nextpos:    pop dx
mov dh, 0x07
mov [es:di], dx
add di, 2
loop nextpos

```
        pop es
        popa
        pop bp
        ret 4
```

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Function which prints the time on screen

printTime:  push bp
mov bp,sp
pusha

```
        push es

        mov ax, 0xB800
        mov es, ax

        mov di, [bp+4]                  ;Location where the time is to be printed

        ;Printing hours
        push word [bp+6]
        add di, 2
        push di
        call printstr
        

        ;Printing Colon
        add di, 6
        mov byte [es:di], ':'


        ;Printing minutes
        push word [bp+8]
        add di, 6
        push di
        call printstr
        

        ;Printing Colon
        add di, 6
        mov byte [es:di], ':'


        ;Printing seconds
        push word [bp+10]
        add di, 2
        push di
        call printstr
        

        ;Printing Colon
        add di, 6
        mov byte [es:di], ':'


        ;Printing milli seconds
        push word [bp+12]
        add di, 2
        push di
        call printstr

        pop es

        popa
        pop bp
        ret 10
```

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Shift Left for Split Mode
;Shift Right for Lap Mode

stopWatch:  pusha
push es

```
        call printLayout
        
    
        push word [cs:ms]
        push word [cs:s]
        push word [cs:min]
        push word [cs:hrs]  

        push 480
        call printTime
            
        cmp byte [cs:startTimer], 1
        jnz dEOI                            ;Using two jumps because of the short range of near jump
```

changeTime: add word [cs:ms], 55
cmp word[cs:ms], 1000
jle modCheck

```
        mov word [cs:ms], 0
        inc word[cs:s]
        cmp word [cs:s], 60
        jnz modCheck
        
        mov word [cs:s], 0
        inc word[cs:min]
        cmp word [cs:min], 60
        jnz modCheck
        
        mov word [cs:min], 0
        inc word[cs:hrs]
        
        jmp modCheck
```

modCheck:   cmp byte [cs:sMode], 1
jz splitMode

```
        cmp byte [cs:lMode], 1
        jz  lapMode
        
        jmp EOI
```

dEOI:       jmp EOI                     ;Using dEOI as an intermediate jump because of the short range of near jump

splitMode:  cmp byte [cs:snapshot], 1
jnz eEOI                        ;Going to use two jumps because of the short range of near jump

```
        mov byte [cs:snapshot], 0

        push word [cs:ms]
        push word [cs:s]
        push word [cs:min]
        push word [cs:hrs]  

        ;Position Calculation
        mov al, 80
        mul byte [cs:location]
        shl ax, 1

        add byte [cs:location], 2

        push ax
        call printTime

        jmp EOI
```

eEOI:      jmp EOI                          ;An intermediate jump to EOI

lapMode:  cmp byte [cs:lapTime], 1
jnz xEOI                        ;Using two intermediate jumps because of the short range of near jumps

```
       mov byte [cs:lapTime], 0


       ;Deducting the previos Lap Time from the original time to get the new Lap Time

       ;Making copy of the original Time
       mov ax, [cs:ms]
       mov bx, [cs:s]
       mov cx, [cs:min]
       mov dx, [cs:hrs]


       ;Subtracting the MilliSeconds
```

l1:        sub ax, [cs:lms]
cmp ax, 0
jge l2

```
       add ax, 1000 
       dec bx
```

l2:        mov [cs:lms],ax

```
       ;Subtracting the Seconds
       sub bx, [cs:ls]
       cmp bx, 0
       jge l3

       add bx, 60
       dec cx
```

l3:        mov [cs:ls],bx

```
       jmp l4                      ;For skipping the xEOI given below
```

xEOI:      jmp EOI                    ;An intermediate jump to EOI

```
       ;Subtracting the Minutes
```

l4:        sub cx, [cs:lmin]
cmp cx, 0
jge l5

```
       add cx, 60
       dec dx
```

l5:        mov [cs:lmin],cx

```
       ;Subtracting the Hours
       sub dx, [cs:lhrs]
       mov [cs:lhrs],dx



       ;After the subtraction is done, print the new lapTime

       push word [cs:lms]
       push word [cs:ls]
       push word [cs:lmin]
       push word [cs:lhrs]  

       ;Position Calculation
       mov al, 80
       mul byte [cs:location]
       shl ax, 1

       add byte [cs:location], 2

       push ax
       call printTime

       jmp EOI
```

EOI:        mov al, 0x20
out 0x20, al

return:     pop es
popa
iret

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

;Driver Function

start:       mov ax, 0
mov es, ax

```
         ;Saving the previous keyboard handler routine
         mov ax, [es:9*4]
         mov [oldkb],ax
         mov ax, [es:9*4+2]
         mov [oldkb+2], ax
        
        
         call clrscr

         ;Hooking the interrupts
         
         cli
         
         ;Keyboard Interrupt
         mov word [es:9*4], kbisr
         mov [es:9*4+2], cs
        
         ;Timer Interrupt
         mov word [es:8*4], stopWatch
         mov [es:8*4+2], cs
         
         sti
         
        
         ;Making it TSR 
         mov dx, start
         add dx, 15
         mov cl, 4
         shr dx, cl
         
         mov ax, 0x3100
         int 21h
```

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I should also point out that TSR's don't work in EMU8086! You will need to assemble and link it to an exe and then run it in something like DOSBox.

Comment: Looking over the code it seems like this was written with NASM assembly syntax  and you tried to assemble with EMU8086 which uses MASM like syntax. The two types of assemblers aren't compatible.

Comment: can you do this code in  emu8086  I need it  because its  my  assignment I need it urgently

Comment: I think there's some errors in your posted formatting

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you calculating the duration of 1 second? Are you using an ISR or is your main program doing it?

Comment: can you help me code in emu8086  (stopwatch)  change  font size and style